# Moving to next project version

Tags: c#

I'm starting on the second version of a large Solution/Project that I created and was wondering about the best way to go about it. I'll be changing allot of the core code, classes and projects of the solution and that makes want to make this into a separate solution and separate repository.

I've never really started on a version 2 before, so if anybody could give me advice on the best way to go about it I would truly appreciate it.

For the record I am coding in C# and using VS2012.

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a Branch in the repository called Version2 or something (maybe a better code name) and do all the new dev work in that. That way you still have the original Trunk if you need to go back to it. Maybe also create a Tag with the current project that will never change so you basically take a snapshot of it before making any substantial changes.

Comment: They're probably not using version control so you should really expand your answer to explain what source control is and suggest a tool to start the process.

Comment: If that's the case, you're talking about a whole new question - the answer to which exists in a 1st year computer science course.

Comment: Thank You this was perfect I created the branch from within VS.

Comment: @DaveDev: Unfortunately, I have never seen a CS course teach version control.

Answer (score 0):

I usually keep everything in one solution and just evolve the solution. There are several benefits to this:

- You refactor your tests along with the project (hope you do have some!)
- Keep a tracked version of all the changes in your source control
- It's easier to make sure your project is still stable after the refactoring by running test suits or running the executables in debug mode
- It is safer to refactor little bits and peaces, than a global re-write, there is a risk you will go a little bit to far with refactoring

Comment: I understand, but in this case I'm expanding the whole concept of the project and thus many of the classes that I wrote are to situation specific to be of any real use.